# SVG Color not implementing

Tags: angular, svg

Using this package [angular-svg-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon) in angular8 for my own svg icons.

**code**

```
<svg-icon
  src="assets/bxs-plane.svg"
  [svgStyle]="{'width.px':30,'fill':'red'}"
></svg-icon>
```

trying to change the color of `svg` but fill element is not working, even try through `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Fill property work on path tag which is present inside svg tag. You need to edit svg content manually to change that fill attribute of path. However doing so is not good thing as you may need to reuse it at multiple place.
Remove attribute fill="colorvalue" from all path element inside svg manually and then we can change fill property of path even if we set it on SVG element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<svg-icon
  src="assets/bxs-plane.svg"
  [applyCss]='true'
  [svgStyle]="{'width.px':30,'fill':'red'}"
></svg-icon>
```